# Tempfiles when using shiny

Tags: r, shiny, temporary-files

I'm developing a shiny application where the user can upload a file and select X parameters, after that he press a button and it generates 5 plots (ggplot2 and barplot) and also a dynamic data table (DT). Also, I want to put my shiny app into a linux server.

I'm using `tempfiles()` for each file I'm using to create the plots and also the DT.

After that, my question is:

When the user closes the shiny app (close the window), do the tempfiles autodelete?

If not, what can I do to delete the tempfiles?

My tries:

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
  if (!is.null(x1)) {
    file.remove(x1)
  }
  if (!is.null(x2)) {
    file.remove(x2)
  }
  if (!is.null(x3)) {
    file.remove(x3)
  }
  if (!is.null(x4)) {
    file.remove(x4)
  }
  if (!is.null(xx)) {
    file.remove(xx)
  }
})
```

Or:

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
  files <- list.files(tempdir(), full.names = T, pattern = "^file")
  file.remove(files)
})
```

With that code I delete the tempfiles when user presses the button once, and if the user presses the button more than 1 time then the window closes, and it will only delete the last generated files. The second part deletes all files at the temp dir but that affects to the other users?(I think yes so that's why I need another solution).

The .png tempfiles generated by ggplot and barplot doesn't autodelete.

My worry is that if the tempfiles won't autodelete and the linux server will collapse because of a lot of tempfiles.

Hope you can solve my doubts. Att Joan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `deleteFile=TRUE` parameter if you want a `render` function to automatically delete your temporary files:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, clientData) {
  output$myImage <- renderImage({
    # A temp file to save the output.
    # This file will be removed later by renderImage
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')

    # Generate the PNG
    png(outfile, width=400, height=300)
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), main="Generated in renderImage()")
    dev.off()

    # Return a list containing the filename
    list(src = outfile,
         contentType = 'image/png',
         width = 400,
         height = 300,
         alt = "This is alternate text")
      }, deleteFile = TRUE)
    })
```

A temp file is created to save the output, and that file is later automatically removed because of the `deleteFile=TRUE` argument.

The default Shiny (`shiny.R`) also has a built-in mechanism that **clear file upload directories** if that's your concern. The following code remove the upload directory when the session ends:

```
registerSessionEndCallbacks = function() {
      # This is to be called from the initialization. It registers functions
      # that are called when a session ends.

      # Clear file upload directories, if present
      self$onSessionEnded(private$fileUploadContext$rmUploadDirs)
    }
```

Another point regarding manually deleting your temp files (as what you were attempting): the plot will have to render every time the user switched to another tab or resize his / her browser window, so if you're manually deleting the file, it may be inefficient since it needs to be re-rendered again. The `onSessionEnded` solution is nicer as it confirms that the session has ended.

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
   if (!is.null(input$file1)) {
    file.remove(input$file1$datapath)
  }
})
```

Comment: If I put `deleteFile = TRUE` will the file delete when the user closes the app or before? Also my idea is deleting all the files that has been created during the user session( I will have more than 5 users ).

Comment: The variable is used to specify if the file should be be deleted **after it is sent to the client browser**. So it is deleted after the `renderImage()` or `renderPlot()` has executed. Generally speaking, if the image is a temp file, then this should be TRUE

Comment: And the second part of my comment? Please

Comment: If you use deleteFile=T for all of the temporary files you’re creating in a user session, there is no “cleaning” process required since all the files that were created was automatically removed. That does solve the problem for you, doesn’t it? Also: as I mentioned in the answer R has built-in handlers to clear your file upload directories too if that’s one of your worries. It is its default behaviour so you don’t need to explicitly code for it.

Comment: My problem is that the app will run 24/7 so when I'm trying the app and after use it close the window, the files won't autodelete because R session won't end. After that I check the tmp directory and there are all the plots images and also the other files (.vcf, .txt).

Comment: Ahhhh ok now it's clearer what your concerns are. Have you considered deleting the whole directory with `unlink(dir1, recursive = T)` periodically? Or when the length of your temp files exceed a certain size for example using `length` on `list.files(tmp_dir, full.names = T, pattern = "^file")`.

Comment: I'd recommend against using `unlink` -- especially `recursive=T` -- in shiny code, it seems far too "close" to being able to do things maliciously (it just feels wrong to me); even if there are no known "exploits" for something like this, it just seems risky. J0ki, typically temp directories have a cleanup cron job on the serving system; if not, I suggest you ensure the OS has a cron job with something like `find ${TMPDIR} -atime 24 -print0 | xargs -0 rm` run every few hours or every day would be a much better/secure method.